# Java app will not display, but the solution must have runnable outside of main class

Tags: java, multithreading, applet, runnable

I am trying to make a simple Java tetris game.  I am following a tutorial on 
[GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/reference/articles/article1360.asp).  I want to go outside the tutorial by keeping the runnable Frame class outside of the main class, rather than putting everything in one class like the tutorial says (the code works if I do so).

This code is my attempt to do the following (below), and I presume that the runnable is called, but the app doesn't display for some reason.

Can someone clarify what I did wrong and what I need to do while keeping my runnable in the Frame class

Main.java class

```
import java.lang.String;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    //boolean victory = false;
    Frame bob = new Frame();
    bob.init();
}
}
```

Frame.java class:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Frame extends Applet implements Runnable {
Thread t;
int i;

public void init()
{
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
    i = 0;
}

public void run()
{
    while(true)
    {
      i++;
      repaint();

      try {
        t.sleep(1000/30);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) { ; }
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawString("i = "+i,10,20);
}
}
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please read tutorial - http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: Why not try making a proper desktop application? It's not really any harder than setting up an applet.

Comment: I've decided to use another tutorial with code structured in a way that is more familiar to me.  http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/Java_Game_Programming/  That kind of makes this question moot, and I apologize for anyone who took the time to understand my problem.  I'm going to leave this question open just long enough until I can make a program in this tutorial that has multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

To run an applet, create an HTML document.

sample.html

```
<applet code="Frame" width="100" height="100"></applet>
```

Now open "sample.html" document in web-browser or from the command-prompt, issue following command

```
>appletviewer sample.html
```